# In Moment.js, how do you get the date of the next occurrence of a specific month (ex: 'next January' => 2013-01-01)?

Tags: momentjs

Examples:

- NOW it's March 26th 2012. I ask for next February. It should return 2013-01-01
- NOW it's March 26th 2012. I ask for next April. It should return 2012-04-01

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
// date is a JS date or moment
// month is the zero indexed month (0 - 11)
function nextMonth(date, month) {
    var input = moment(date);
    var output = input.clone().startOf('month').month(month);
    return output > input ? output : output.add(1, 'years');
}
```

See the documentation on manipulating a moment. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/

Comment: That would return the month I asked for NEXT YEAR. What I want is the closest occurrence of that month in the future. I rephrased my question above. ex: NOW it's March 26th 2012. I ask for next April. It should return 2012-04-01

Comment: I made a Feature request in your repo: https://github.com/timrwood/moment/issues/559 Maybe somebody is working on something similar? Otherwise when I finish writing my functions I can try to refactor them somehow into moment.js?

Comment: Awesome! Very clever! The only thing is it seems to take input by reference (meaning it changes input). Instead maybe: `/**
         * date: JS date or moment
         * month: the zero indexed month (0 - 11)
         */
        nextMonth: function(date, month) {
            var input = moment(date);
            var output = moment(input).startOf('month').month(month);
            return output > input ? output : output.add('years', 1);
        },`

Answer (score 2):

Wrote this:

```
    /**
        @var date is a JS date or moment
        @var month is the month in the 0-11 format
     */
    var getNextMonthOccurrence: function(date, month){
        var m = moment(date);

        var this_year = new Date(m.year(), month, 1);
        var next_year = new Date(m.year() + 1, month, 1);

        return this_year > m ? this_year : next_year;
    }
```

But there's got to be a better way of doing it...

Answer (score 1):

Next January 1st: 
`moment().month(0+12).date(1).hour(0).minute(0).second(0)`

Next March 17th:
`moment().month(2).date(17).hour(0).minute(0).second(0)`

edit: you just need to pay attention to whether the created date is less than now. Since it's currently february, getting next january needs to add 12 months, but getting next march doesn't.

```
function getNextJan(){
    var j = moment().month(0).date(1).hour(0).minute(0).second(0)
    if(j < moment()) return j.month(12)
    return j
}
```