# How to get recurring dates using moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, momentjs

In my scenario I have an start date and end date

```
const startDate = 2018-11-07  // YYYY-MM-DD format and it is Wednesday

const endDate = 2018-12-01
```

I am getting a flag from UI where event need to be repeated weekly from start date to end date

How can I get event dates that fall in that range?

Expecting result approx to `["2018-11-07", "2018-11-14", .... ,"2018-11-28"]`

Comment: you will need another param which is recurring interval, in your case it is 7. When you have that interval just keep adding that interval in start date until it is smaller than end date, while loop may be?

Comment: Another solution would be to use `recur` plugin for momentjs https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/10-plugins/10-recur/

Comment: You can inspire from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047063/in-moment-js-how-do-you-get-the-date-of-the-next-occurrence-of-a-specific-month#answer-14047456

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply utilize the official moment plugin [moment-range](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/range/):

```
const Moment = require('moment');
const MomentRange = require('moment-range');
const moment = MomentRange.extendMoment(Moment);

const range = moment.range(moment('2018-11-07'), moment('2018-12-01'));

console.log(Array.from(range.by('week')))
```

Outputs:

```
[ moment("2018-11-07T00:00:00.000"),
  moment("2018-11-14T00:00:00.000"),
  moment("2018-11-21T00:00:00.000"),
  moment("2018-11-28T00:00:00.000") ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `moment-range` as Akrion mentioned.

But You can simply make Your own helper method.

Take it:

```
const moment = require('moment');

const generateDateRange = (from, to, step = 1, modifier = 'day', format = 'YYYY-MM-DD') => {
  const dates = [];

  let currentDate = moment(from);
  const lastDate = moment(to);

  while(currentDate <= lastDate) {
    dates.push(currentDate.format(format));
    currentDate = currentDate.add(step, modifier);
  }

  return dates;
}


const dates = generateDateRange('2018-11-07', '2018-12-01', 1, 'week');
console.log(dates);
```

Test [here](https://repl.it/@num8er/generateDateRangeWithMoment)